# Java split string and remove

Tags: java, regex, parsing, substring

I have a `String` that I need to search through and basically extract all numbers greater than 3 digits from, and also split at a certain point and only take those values from before the split.

Here's the string

```
String str = "where filter_2_id = 20003 and (acceptable_flag is true or acceptable_flag is null)  and  filter_2_id IN (20003)  AND filter_5_id IN (50053, 50014)  AND filter_1_id IN ( 10000 )  AND filter_2_id IN ( 20000, 20001, 20002, 20003, 20004 )";
```

Basically the `String` may or may not have the "AND filter_1_id..." and everything after it, but I need to search and see if the `String` contains that. If it does, I want to remove that and anything after. I am using regex to parse out the numbers, but I do not need 1 or 2 digit numbers. Here's a sample I did but it is not taking into account the split or removing 1-2 digit numbers.

```
public class FilterTest {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        doMagic();
    }

    public static void doMagic(){
        String str = "where filter_2_id = 20003 and (acceptable_flag is true or acceptable_flag is null)  and  filter_2_id IN (20003)  AND filter_5_id IN (50053, 50014)  AND filter_1_id IN ( 10000 )  AND filter_2_id IN ( 20000, 20001, 20002, 20003, 20004 )";
        //String parsedString = StringUtils.trimWhitespace(str);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);

        List<String> numberList = new ArrayList<String>();

        if( m.find() ){
            do {
                String local = m.group();
                System.out.println(local);
                numberList.add(local);
            } while(m.find());
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output I am getting now:
2
20003
2
20003
5
50053
50014
1
10000
2
20000
20001
20002
20003
20004

I need this:
20003
20003
50053
50014

Comment: what result do you want from your example?

Comment: Well I basically need to get them into a list, but I also need to convert all them to Integer also. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the additional information. Please specify exactly, what output you expect and what output you get.

Comment: You're getting dangerously close to the point where you should parse this "expression."

Comment: If one of the answers below answered your question, the way this site works, you'd "accept" the answer, more here: What should I do when someone answers my question?(http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). But only if your question really has been answered. If not, consider adding more details to the question.

Comment: I did but it said I have to earn a 15 "reputation" first before it displays

Answer (score 0):

The regex you are using `\\d+` will look for 1 or more digits that is why you are getting single digit numbers as well.
You need to change the regular expression to `\\d{3}\\d*` to look for 3 or more digits.

Use split to split the string on filter_1_id. Then use the 1st string in the resultant array. `String[] tokens = str.split("filter_1_id");`

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

class FilterTest
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        doMagic();
    }

    public static void doMagic(){
        String str = "where filter_2_id = 20003 and (acceptable_flag is true or acceptable_flag is null)  and  filter_2_id IN (20003)  AND filter_5_id IN (50053, 50014)  AND filter_1_id IN ( 10000 )  AND filter_2_id IN ( 20000, 20001, 20002, 20003, 20004 )";
        //String parsedString = StringUtils.trimWhitespace(str);
        String[] tokens = str.split("filter_1_id");
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{3}\\d*)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(tokens[0]);

        List<String> numberList = new ArrayList<String>();

        if( m.find() ){
            do {
                String local = m.group();
                System.out.println(local);
                numberList.add(local);
            } while(m.find());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ashutosh, if i needed these numbers to be an Integer array, is there a simple way to do that using this code above?

Comment: @Buccaneer you can change the `numberList` array to be of type `List<Integer>` and then add the number to the list by parsing it as an Integer `numberList.add(Integer.parseInt(local))`

Answer (score 0):

Regex Pattern

```
 \d{m,}   // allows numbers of having m or more digits.
 \d{m,n}  // allows numbers of between m and n digits.
```

For your current issue use

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{3,})");
```